# Why my scanner still takes a space char

Tags: java

Input : 1 2 3

Goal : Each of this number will be filled in a same array. Space will be excluded.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String  n = in.nextLine();
System.out.println(n);

int[] nums = new int[n.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {
     System.out.println(n.charAt(i));
     if (!String.valueOf(n.charAt(i)).equalsIgnoreCase(" ")) {
          nums[i] = Character.getNumericValue(n.charAt(i));
     }
}
```

I've no idea why still it includes space *`" "`*.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: Clearly this is not working `if (!String.valueOf(n.charAt(i)).equalsIgnoreCase(" "))`

Comment: Hi I do manually checking but of course the debugger showed  the elemens are not empty.. This is a fragment of a huge codes I might be too tired.

Comment: either take out the ! or take out "ignoreCase" both of them together are giving the opposite desired outcome.

Comment: I embedded it because `" "!= ' '`, but let me try it out. EDIT : nope still the same behavior shown in the console.

Comment: Why do you do `!String.valueOf(n.charAt(i)).equalsIgnoreCase(" ")`? It would be simpler and more readable to say `n.charAt(i) != ' '`...

Comment: Actually I saw nothing wrong with it, at least visually.

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone look again at answers, i've a 2-lines one ;)

Comment: @azro, Thank you very much for reviewing the answer.

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone review what ? you have accepted a non-complet and not the most efficient one ..

Comment: Well.. I'm going away to far far away, bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you did this, number of elements in nums array will be the same as number of characters in "n". And in places char is space, you will get value 0.
You can try it this way:

```
    String[] numStrings = n.split("\\D+");
    int[] nums = new int[numStrings.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (String num : numStrings) {
        nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(num);
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: This does not work if you enter like 2 spaces next to each other, or special char or letter ..

Comment: Dang..it, this won't work on the second, adjacent space. EDIT : I missed your edit. Thank you. Accepted again and plus one.

Answer (score 3):

One simple way to achieve that, is by doing something like this:

```
String  n = in.nextLine().replace(" ", "");
int nums[] = new int[n.length()];
int i=0;
for(char c : n.toCharArray()) {
    nums[i++] = Character.getNumericValue(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the input line using:

```
String  n = in.nextLine();
String[] splitLine = n.split(" ");
for (String s : splitLine){
   //you can save the num in an array
   int num = Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is code is that you increment `i` event when the `char` you look at is a space you so you'll have empty places into your array `nums`

---

You can easily fix this with :

```
String n = in.nextLine().replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

I will remove all `non-digit characters` from what you type and so after you won't have to check :

```
int[] nums = new int[n.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++){
    nums[i] = Character.getNumericValue(n.charAt(i));
}
```

---

Or in less lines using Java8 features (you can even put in 1^^) :

```
String n = in.nextLine().replaceAll("\\D", "");
int[] nums = Arrays.stream(n.split("")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

After erase all non-digit, the second line will split every into an array, then cast to `int` and then convert into an `array`

Comment: But correct me If I'm wrong that the `!String.valueOf(n.charAt(i)).equalsIgnoreCase(" ")` says do not take any space chars.

Comment: yes normally, but for me it prints only digits with a empty boxes, if you print all element at the end what do you have ?

Comment: He has edited it anyway. No coming back, I'had given it to him already I just won't take it back. As my thank, extra stuff will be sent, don't ask me about what I'm talking about. Lol

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone ok, i've see, thanks :p I'll remove my comments they are useless now

Comment: No do not. Don't just remove things, so that the future readers might somehow trace the reasons/logics/anything behind the problem itself.

Answer (score 1):

I changed `.equalsIgnoreCase` to `.equals` and used a Pointer for insertion to the array.

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String  n = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(n);
        int pointer = 0;

        int[] nums = new int[n.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {

            if (!String.valueOf(n.charAt(i)).equals(" ")) {

            nums[pointer] = Character.getNumericValue(n.charAt(i));
            pointer++;

             }
        }
```